# Real time IPC in Unix userspace

Tags: c++, unix, real-time, ipc, producer-consumer

I wanted to ask for the best approach for the following problem:
I have two distinct processes: producer, and consumer.
The producer produces items, where each item is an unsigned int. and the consumer consumes them, the different from regular consumer producer problem is that the consumer needs to know the exact time of the item production.
The consumer cannot trust the producer, so the producer shouldn't supply the time together with the item, what force the consumer to ask the system for the current time at the moment he consumes an item.
All this need to be performed with less as possibles effects on the producer since the producer is a real time application.

I tried to read about IPC mechanism in Unix but I didn't find something that can meet those constraints.
The consumer and the producer are written in c++.

Any idea would be welcome,
Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose you want the time between an item being produced and it being consumed to be as small as possible, no? So the consumer itself should be a realtime application as well. Otherwise you could just consume things from the consume at your leisure, with a process of regular priority, and let the kernel take care of not having the processes step on their toes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a shared memory between the producer and consumer.
2. Poll for an event on consumer side to minimize the delay.
3. Pin consumer thread to a CPU to prevent context switches (CPU affinity).
4. Use Timer Stamp Counter (TSC) to avoid long "get time" syscalls.

That will give you the most precise results.

Sure, having other requirements in hand, you could sacrifice some of the items above to make your consumer application more CPU-efficient or less complicated... It is up to you.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know about Timer Stamp Counter, I will look on that. It still not enough since the consumer still needs to wait for the next context switch.

Comment: @TomerGolomb what do you mean? Consumer must poll for an event to avoid any context switches (#2)